# maui: showing picture from gallery not working

Tags: maui

Im grabbing a picture from the gallery like described in the docs. that works, I can pick the pictures in my ios gallery and I am getting a full stream:

```
        string localFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

        using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
        using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

         await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            img_profilePic.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => localFileStream);
            img_profilePic.IsVisible = true;
        });
```

But when I try to set the image to the imagesource of my image from xaml, nothing changes in the UI.

If I change the image to a local image however, it updates the UI. So it must be something with the stream.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: have you tried resetting the position of `localFileStream` to the begining?

Comment: @Jason, Hi, I tried:  localFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); but that didnt change the outcome. Any other ways to resetting the stream?